# Spring boot management.metrics.distribution exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, application.properties

I'm trying to set the values of these two properties in my spring boot `application.properties` file -

```
management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value=1
management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value=10
```

or

```
management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value=1s
management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value=10s
```

Every-time I try to run my application with these two fields set, I get below exception -

`APPLICATION FAILED TO START\n***************************\n\nDescription:\n\nFailed to bind properties under 'management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>:\n\n    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]\n\nAction:\n\nUpdate your application's configuration\n"}`

I'm going through the doc, but they don't have shown any example how to set those values properly - [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1.0-RC1-Configuration-Changelog#:~:text=management.metrics.distribution,minimum%2Dexpected%2Dvalue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1.0-RC1-Configuration-Changelog#:%7E:text=management.metrics.distribution,minimum%2Dexpected%2Dvalue)

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those properties are for configuring per-meter maximums and you haven't include a meter name. For example, to configure a maximum of `10s` for meter names starting with `example.meter`, you would configure `management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value.example.meter=10s`.

The reference documentation contains [a section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.customizing.per-meter-properties) on per-meter properties.

Comment: Is there a way to set minimum and maximum globally without including the meter name?

Comment: There’s no way to do that as it is highly unlikely that the same minimum or maximum will be appropriate for every metric.